# init a kubernetes cluster with kubeadm but public IP on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-kubeadm-on-ubuntu-18-04

Important difference: 
I need to run the `master` on a specific node, and the `worker` nodes are *from different* regions on AWS.

So it all went well until I wanted to join the nodes (step 5). The command succeeded but `kubectl get nodes` still only showed the `master` node.

I looked at the `join` command and it contained the `master` 's **private** ip address:
`join 10.1.1.40`. I guess that can not work if the workers are in a different region (note: later we probably need to add nodes from different providers even, so if there is no important security threat, it should work via public IPs).

So while `kubeadm init pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` initialized the cluster but with this internal IP, I then tried with
`kubeadm init  --apiserver-advertise-address <Public-IP-Addr> --apiserver-bind-port 16443  --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`

But then it always hangs, and init does not complete. The kubelet log prints lots of

`E0610 19:24:24.188347 1051920 kubelet.go:2267] node "ip-x-x-x-x" not found`

where "ip-x-x-x-x" seems to be the master's node hostname on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I think what made it work is that I set the master's hostname to its **public** DNS name, and then used that as `--control-plane-endpoint` argument..., without `--apiserver-advertise-address` (but with the `--apiserver-bind-port` as I need to run it on another port).

Need to have it run longer to confirm but so far looks good.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and I solved the same way. But I am having a problem in getting logs of the pods deployed in the worker nodes. The kubectl logs command is looking into private ip address of the worker node. Did you had this issue?